# ASP.Net or WPF (C#)?

Tags: asp.net, wpf

Our team is divided on this and I wanted to get some third-party opinions.

We are building an application and cannot decide if we want to use .Net WPF Desktop Application with a WCF server, or ASP.Net web app using jQuery. I thought I'd ask the question here, with some specs, and see what the pros/cons of using either side would be. I have my own favorite and feel I am biased.

Ideally we want to build the initial release of the software as fast as we can, then slow down and take time to build in the additional features/components we want later on. Above all we want the software to be fast. Users go through records all day long and delays in loading records or refreshing screens kills their productivity.

Application Details:

- I'm estimating around 100 different screens for initial version, with plans for a lot of additional screens being added on later after the initial release.
- We are looking to use two-way communication for reminder and event systems
- Currently has to support around 100 users, although we've been told to allow for growth up to 500 users
- We have multiple locations

Items to consider (maybe not initially in some cases but in future releases):

- Room for additional components to be added after initial release (there are a lot of of these... perhaps work here than the initial application)
- Keyboard navigation
- Performance is a must
- Production Speed to initial version
- Low maintenance overhead
- Future support
- Softphone/Scanner integration

Our Developers:

- We have 1 programmer who has been learning WPF the past few months and was the one who suggested we use WPF for this.
- We have a 2nd programmer who is familiar with ASP.Net and who may help with the project in the future, although he will not be working on it much up until the initial release since his time is spent maintaining our current software.
- There is me, who has worked with both and am comfortable in either
- We have an outside company doing the project management, and they are an ASP.Net company.
- We plan on hiring 1-2 others, however we need to know what direction we are going in first

Environment:

- General users are on Windows 2003 server with Terminal Services. They connect using WYSE thin-clients over an RDP connection. Admin staff has their own PCs with XP or higher. Users are allowed to specify their own resolution although they are limited to using IE as the web browser.
- Other locations connects to our network over a MPLS connection

Based on that, what would you choose and why?

I am especially interested in hearing from developers who have experience with both ASP.Net and WPf.

Comment: What is this going to be ? Something like a CRM system ? You might want to look for existing products and build on them instead of constructing the whole thing from scratch.

Comment: We have looked at existing products, but nothing out there suits our business needs. The idea is to build something that combines the best of what we've seen and integrate our own ideas.

Comment: Is this going to be deployed on a company intranet or similar, where you are comfortable pushing new versions?

Comment: @cwap: Yes it will be deployed on the company intranet. If we go with ASP.Net, updating is obviously easy, and if we go with WPF we will be building an auto-updater that gets run when they connect to the WCF server.

Comment: @Rachel - How goes the project? It's been a few months. Did you go WPF? I'm very interested in your perception about the relative productivity of WPF and ASP.NET. If you have an opinion about that -- here's my question. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490456/is-wpf-development-faster-or-slower-than-classic-asp-net-web-forms

Comment: @hoytster Yes we are going with WPF and so far I am loving it. Creating the UI I want is so easy compared to asp.net and I am not limited by browser limitations. I feel it is faster to program in and much more enjoyable to work with, although there was a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: This was a bad question for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/19893/asp-net-or-wpfc) and is even more out-of-place here as it is also off-topic.  I cannot believe it has so many upvotes.

Comment: Given the environment, I would consider Silverlight. I know it's an old post, so a lot has changed. Good question BTW.

Comment: @Rachel - First of all just so you know, I began studying WPF and I'm reading you blog as well which is a great source of information. Do you might also consider making it a full tutorial?
Also, regarding this specific post - Will WPF still have made a good choice if you wanted to make an application which you would distribute world wide? Or is then ASP.NET be a must?

Comment: @YonatanNir I don't think I'd have time to make a full tutorial, but I'll consider it if I ever have a large block of free time :) As for if WPF can be distributed world wide, I don't see why not providing you know your audience. I think WPF only works on Windows, and I would really recommend the .Net Framework 4.0+ which not everyone has on their machines. In addition, there might be security/trust issues with your application depending on what it does. WPF is a desktop technology which has access to the local file system, while ASP.Net is a web technology which has limited access

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Reasons to choose WPF:

- Much faster and easier development than ASP.NET and jQuery
- Much easier to implement quick incremental background loading of data
- Much easier to implement client-side caching of commonly used data (important for remote offices)
- More efficient data transfer from server (can use advanced WCF features unavailable to web browser)
- Keyboard navigation better, since you can easily define shortcuts, etc, and not be limited by browser
- Maintenance overhead *much* better using MVVM pattern
- Softphone integration easy

Reasons to choose ASP.NET and jQuery:

- None that I can see

In your scenario I would definitely choose WPF.

Comment: "Reasons to choose WPF: •Much faster and easier development than ASP.NET and jQuery"

You must be using a different version of wpf than me. Take something as basic as input validation where one field depends on another as see how hard it is to achieve in wpf

Comment: I do that kind of input validation regularly. What do you find difficult about it?  More to the point:  How long have you been using WPF versus ASP.NET, and are you using MVVM for your WPF development?  WPF is just a whole lot less code and a whole lot less debugging, so it is faster and easier to develop.

Comment: I've done basic input/validation in both ASP.Net and WPF and I do find it easier in WPF. Validation is easy to build into the Models (or ViewModels if data comes from multiple models) and the UI automatically picks up validation errors and displays the validation  error template.

Comment: EF + MVC also has automatic validation.
Anyways, it would be so much easier for me to develop this in the web environment, since I know it, and I don't know WPF. So #1 point is arguable.

Comment: @Artemiy: Last spring I had seven hours to teach a group of high school kids to program. I taught them WPF/Silverlight. By the end of the class they were writing programs a EF + MVC programmer might spend days on. Unless it's a tiny project, it is generally faster to learn WPF and then use it than to use EF + MVC. Rachel says her project will have around 100 screens for the initial version. Even starting from zero WPF knowlege, WPF would still be faster and easier. This assumes you have at least one WPF mentor around (or you could use StackOverflow).

Comment: I agree, that WPF is a much better designed system, compared to the mess that web programming is. But I hope you are not suggesting that they develop this software with zero initial knowledge of either.

Comment: Like I said in my original question, I am comfortable with both ASP.Net and WPF. Since one of my teammates is WPF only and the other is ASP.Net only, we are trying to identify which is the better technology for our program.

Comment: @Artemiy:  My phrase "even starting from zero WPF knowledge" was actually directed at your statement "I don't know WPF."  The point I was trying to make was that even you, who know no WPF, would be able to develop a large application faster in WPF than in ASP.NET/etc, since the WPF's learning time would more than pay for itself in the dramatically more efficient development.

Comment: All reasons above are valid for Silverlight too. Plus SL has much better deployment story, than ClickOnce & Windows.

Comment: @Lex:  It appears that you are unaware of WPF's ability to work within a web browser.  FYI, you can run a WPF application in the web browser just like Silverlight, either full-page (requiring no HTML) or in a portion of the web page.  The only requirement is that the client be running Windows with NET Framework installed.  Communication with the server can be done via WCF, Web Services, REST, or many other ways.

Comment: I'm very well aware, but since it works only in IE, nobody really considers it as a web application. Silverlight works in every major browser (including Mac)

Comment: You are wrong. On Windows I've personally used WPF inside IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. What Silverlight brings to the table is cross-platform capability - the ability to run on Mac, Linux, WinPho7, etc. The tradeoff is that Silverlight is still missing some of the very best features of WPF, such as MarkupExtension.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, I would sit down and write the business requirements and specifications. It really doesn't matter what tech you use - proper planning will affect your project timeline more than technology choice. This is especially true for an in-house custom built app.

As far as development, I would take the requirements and lay out the backend functionality. I would actually implement the backend in WCF, regardless of the client technology - that way you could use best of both worlds if needed (for example for phone integration you could write a stand-alone WPF app). ASP.NET with jQuery can easily use WCF services (JSON or XML version) together with desktop client.

As far as development of the client forms, this highly depends on developers experience and your future plans. I am not going to go into advantages/disadvantages of developing web software here - there are a ton of articles in the last 10 years about cloud/web based software (for example salesforce). I would rather concentrate on deliverables - what is your team most comfortable with today and in the future. There's a huge difference between WPF and web development, from development standpoint, and it requires completely different experience.

Comment: I agree, there should almost always be a service layer that different interfaces can connect to, that way you can separate data/logic from presentation and interaction

Answer (score 9):

Why not consider a hybrid solution - Silverlight

With Silverlight you get most of the goodness and statefullness of WPF (with almost exactly the same XAML and code), plus you get the deployment characteristics of ASP.NET

Many people consider Silverlight the next step after ASP.NET/AJAX, and it would definitely deliver all of the benefits of WPF relevant to your scenario.

Comment: We have considered Silverlight, but prefer WPF because it has a larger control library and more features than Silverlight.

Comment: @Rachel: Having used WPF to build similar line-of-business apps for just over a year, and then spending the last two months building a Silverlight line-of-business app, I agree that for the given scenario WPF is a superior choice to Silverlight for the the reasons you state.

Comment: Silverlight is WPF on steroids.
1) SL is web technology, so no problem with deployment/update.
2) SL is presentation framework, so architecture is by definition multitier.
3) SL has already rich stack of controls (commercials and free)
4) SL is more crossplatform than WPF.
5) SL uses almost the same XAML as WPF.
6) SL has Ria Services & Wcf Data Services to advance web entity access.
7) Softphone/Scanner could be implemented via COM-interop.

So if you need Windows only solution, I would personally go with WinForms, because of superior control base. If you need web - SL if way to go.

Comment: @Lex: Your comment shows some gaps in your understanding of WPF:  1. WPF supports web deployment which is indistinguishable from Silverlight for the end-user, 2. WPF does multitier better than Silverlight, 3. WPF has a bigger stack of controls, 5. WPF has more XAML features, 6. WPF has more, 7. WPF has P/Invoke, *full* COM interop, HwndSource, etc so 
Softphone/Scanner interop will likely be much easier (also COM-interop eliminates Silverlight's one advantage). Bottom line: Silverlight is great, but WPF still wins in every category except multiplatform ability.

Comment: @Ray: Sorry, no gaps here. Worked both with SL and WPF. 1) From my experience, WPF has xbap (IE only, useless, no OOB), WPF/WinForms has ClickOnce which is usable, but still SL xap files are way easier and cleaner deployment solution for OOB and Browser web apps. So no, SL has much better deployment story.

Comment: @Ray: 2) WPF does multitier better than Silverlight? What do you mean here? Any examples?
3) WPF has more controls, true, but SL has already rich component stack. Check DevExpress, Telerik, Infragistics - all have their SL suites ready.
5) WPF has more XAML features (yes, I know, more complicated bindings, bindings in styles), but I don't feel somebody really misses them.
6) Any examples of WPF having more?
7) COM interop available in SL is enough for Windows. On OS X it would be soon possible to call OS X COM analogue.

Comment: @Lex: 1) XBAP works with IE, Firefox, Chrome.  Obviously WPF has out-of-browser capability(!).  And yes, the OOB transition can work identically to Silverlight if you set it up correctly.  2&6) One such example is my own EDF framework which requires a bunch of ugliness under the hood to work with Silverlight because of Silverlight's lack of advanced bindings, its DependencyObject limitations, and its communication limitations.  Silverlight is **fantastic**, but WPF is **even better** as long as you don't need to go cross-platform.

Comment: @Lex: 7) Many Windows APIs don't have a COM+ interface, or they use types and marshalling not available in Silverlight.  This problem is even more common with third-party apps such as Smartphone software.  With WPF you know you can use *any* Windows API simply and easily.  With Silverlight you may have to break out the C++ with ATL and start writing COM+ shims which must then get installed on the target, etc, etc.  And it is even more difficult in Silverlight to embed a Smartphone vendor's Win32-based UI inside your own.  On the other hand in WPF this is a piece of cake.

Comment: @Ray, 1) I just checked Xbap in Chrome. It offers me to save file on disk... Is this your deployment story? 2) DependencyObject limitations? DependencyObjects are used in UI, why do you need them in EDF, INotifyPropertyChanged works at least 20% faster than DependencyProperties? Yes, SL has some communication limitations like policy files, lack of WS*- web-services, but for web application this dosn't really matter. TCP Sockets work fine, client http stack works fine, what else do one need more in web application?

Comment: 7) It's exactly my point, that writing a platform specific COM object to incapsulate platform code is way better approach, that P/Invoke here and there, tie your client code to Windows, to specific dlls and then face code migration apocalypse. Writing separate standalone COM object for designated OS will save one a lot of troubles.

Comment: What I hear you saying is "Yes, WPF has some advanced features Silverlight doesn't have.  Are all those extra features really all that important?"  No, actually they're not:  You can work around Silverlight's limitations.  But WPF doesn't have these limitations, so a WPF developer's life is easier.  That's my point.  Example:  In Silverlight you **must** create the COM+ encapsulating object as a separate project and install it separately.  In WPF you can choose to create exactly the same encapsulation as a class within your application, or you can choose to not encapsulate.  It's up to you.

Comment: -1 for saying the word "Silverlight"

Answer (score 5):

WPF is the way to go, without a doubt. I agree with all that @Ray Burns has said.

Because:

- You will get a richer, slicker, faster application.
- It will be easier to build<sup>1</sup>.
- Softphone/Scanner (i.e. hardware) integration is going to require browser plugins etc. and this can be a nightmare with a browser based application.
- Keyboard navigation is still better with native applications.
- IME Maintenance is easier with WPF applications.

Definitely use WCF to provide the backend via The Entity Framework, see [The Entity Framework In Layered Architectures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700340.aspx).  You can do have a  better integration with the backend in a native application because it can be called inline - no need for callbacks or ajax. I've built components for WPF that are linked via EF to the business logic to provide aware controls for simple stuff like validation. It's stunningly good to drop a customer name field onto a form and it just works.

To add additional components you need to build it with a proper well thought out plugin architecture. This is the same in both environments. I've got some thoughts on this I jotted down in my journal entitled [Designing a plugin architecture for an application](http://chateau-logic.com/content/designing-plugin-architecture-application)

When building a WPF application you will be writing in one language (e.g. C#) + markup (XAML). When building asp.net you endup with two languages + markup, as you always have to code some Javascript.

So, based on your requirements it has be to WPF / WCF (EF). A web based application will be a lot more work, more complexity, and not be as nice.

About 12 months ago I was fortunate enough to be given a free hand to choose the technology for a new application. I spent almost a month evaluating all of the options and came to the [conclusion](http://chateau-logic.com/content/building-modern-application-net) that it had to be C#, WPF, Entity Framework. After writing the application I can confirm that it was the right choice...

---

<sup>1</sup>. It will still be easier even if your programmers have to learn WPF first. WPF is much better thought out, great and lovely. very lovely. It just works right.

Comment: @Plugin Architecture, for future visitors: MEF is quite easy to use and learn too.

Answer (score 4):

Hi
I think `The question at issue is Windows-application or Web application`(WPF for win-app VS asp for web-app), **Which one is better for you and your project?**. In this case your platform is network and your program must work on the net. so for this usage Web-app is better but there are a lot points existing which can make decisions hard. Network platform has great challenge.(according to my personal experience)

Working with web-app by asp.net is nearly hard. you must try to handle many thing's for web-app(request time, session management, even poor UI in comparison  to WPF, j-query, etc ). Remember this is not as easy as simple web site.

But win-app is good for network with this condition: "local network"(mpls is almost the same). Absolutely developing win-app is easier than web-app ("At least number of users expert in net-program developing"). for this case WPF has many good things(UI , command, etc) also has many challenging point(like multi-threading and lack of expert developer in this field ) . `I'm rather with wpf than asp but decisions is yours`

And **chalk** point to good thing Silverlight but if you want to use this you must look at prism framework : http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/
I have recently developed a project separately with asp and silverlight(prism framework). developing silver-light version is too hard and takes more time than asp.net version `but at the end SL-ver have great look nothing else!`

**Burns** pointed to good issues about wpf. also consider **Artemiy's** post. your environment conditions is same for both of them. WPF/ASP can work with scanner and soft-phone `cuz the base of both is on C# and .net library`
Finally what ever your decisions is you must hire advance developer at least develop one business-app for the network platform.

Comment: Developing asp.net version is too hard and takes more time, because of ajax, jquery, javascript, browser fine-tuning etc. Developing Silverlight version is much simpler, because of C#, .NET libraries, XAML, shared code (between server & client) and incomparable debugging story.

Comment: @Lex:  Totally agree.  +1 for mentioning debugging story.

Comment: @Lex my mean developing silver-light with prism pattern not simple silver light. you know presenter, interface, controller, service, etc Make both developing and debugging hard.

Comment: You better not use Prism then. There are plenty of easier frameworks out there, like Caliburn.Micro or MVVM light.

Answer (score 3):

Is your app a desktop app or web app.

If Desktop wpf is best.
If web based asp.net is best.

Don't front load your development with your get it up quick scenario. That never works well and results in a sloppy deployment. Take your time, cover all the steps (Business Requirements, System Design, Program Design, Code, TEST and TEST some more, Deployment)

Comment: ... thats in my question - "We are building an application and cannot decide if we want to use .Net WPF **Desktop Application** with a WCF server, or ASP.Net **web app** using jQuery". Thanks though :)

Answer (score 2):

Some points to be made for ASP.NET:

The pool of ASP.NET developers is much larger then the pool of WPF developers. 
Which means you can probably find qualified ASP.NET developers easier.

ASP.NET is probably more future proof, chances of WPF getting large changes and being hard to port to later versions is probably larger. 
Also keep in mind that the focus of MS seems to be on Silverlight so there might be a consolidation down the road which makes WPF obsolete.

More mature eco system of ASP.NET makes for more out of the box solutions to use to solve problems.

With multiple locations you might be able to skip a few layers and go directly to a website?

Comment: I agree about the developer pool, though I don't know how significant that is in this economy.  I disagree about the future-proof.  ASP.NET is getting old, fragile, and bloated.  WPF is moving out onto devices in the form of Silverlight.  Sooner or later we will see WPF / Silverlight targeting HTML5 and then ASP.NET will be history.

Comment: Just thought it would be fun to update on this comment because it was about predicting the future.  ASP.NET is now being replaced by ASP.NET Core to make it work on all platforms and be less bloated. Silverlight has development cut, but WPF is once again getting updates but they are focused on windows desktop.