# Relative effort/productivity to develop business application in Silverlight/WPF or ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, asp.net-mvc, silverlight

I'd like some vague guidelines about the relative effort to build using ASP.NET versus Silverlight/WPF. I know, it all depends, but any input greatly appreciated.

I'm rebuilding a winforms app and planning on moving it to either:

- ASP.NET (could be MVC or webforms), or
- Silverlight (4) or WPF with ClickOnce deployment.

It's a typical business-style app with some tens of forms, various datagrids, standard windows controls, etc. Some chart graphics but no multimedia. It's not *very* data-heavy, i.e. there are quite a few datagrids but they'd seldom have more than 10 cols & 100 rows and usually less. The logic is currently tightly coupled with the winforms code so either way it'll need to be split out from the UI. We also use Crystal Reports for reporting.

The 2-3 developers who will be working on this have some WPF & ASP.NET experience but not much.

I'm tempted to use Telerik controls or similar as they look like they make some things we want to do easier.

The app is installed for a customer and only used internally within their firewall. The main advantage to ASP.NET would be deployment, but I figure that silverlight or wpf with clickonce wouldn't be much worse for deployment and may be faster to build.

If there's any other general information I can provide which will make it easier to estimate relative effort, let me know!

thanks.

UPDATE:

Let's assume the only basis for my decision is the speed/productivity of development (i.e. ignore deployment, UI impact, etc). Which should I choose?

Comment: You simply can't compare a Asp.net site with Silverlight and WPF.  They are in different worlds.

Comment: @jfar, whatever about WPF, there is a huge ambiguity regarding the overlap of ASPNET/Silverlight and when one should be used over the other.

Comment: You have to decide if you want to develop on the server side (ASP.NET) or client side (WPF). If it's a typical WinForms app I'd be tempted to move it over to Silverlight, if it was WebForms I'd go with ASP.NET.

Comment: I've updated to be more clear: for the purposes of this question I don't care whether it's server- or client-side. I just want to know how fast they are to develop, relative to each other and assuming my developers are approximately as inexperienced in each.

Comment: @Rory - Even with all developers being equal ( which they are not ) speed of development time can't even be estimated because it all depends on how you actually implement functionality using the technology.  Are you going to drag and drop Silveright controls on the designer or do you roll your own XAML?  Do you hand code every form with Asp.net or use a auto form component with MVC?

Comment: Well, the developers _are_ equal: they're the same developers. Feel free to make assumptions about implementation strategy. I'm just wanting a general estimate, which I believe it is possible to make for technologies generally (I just don't have the experience for these technologies). If it was ASP.NET webforms versus winforms I'd say winforms would generally be faster, because of less plumbing etc. I haven't described the app very much but assume a standard, boring business app with say 30 forms that are mostly data in-out or wizards. Any major learning curve could be factored in too :)

Comment: I asked a very similar question recently. You might be interested in some of the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207525/asp-net-or-wpf-c

Comment: What have your developers been doing if they're relative experience in both is the same? Have they been primarily developing apps for the desktop, or for the web? In a windows environment or other OSes? I'm primarily a desktop guy, so I'll always say desktop is easier. A co-worker is primarily web, so he'll say web is just as easy.  If you survey your developers, you'll probably gain an insight from their answers regarding what they would be most comfortable doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you use and how cost effective the project will be totally depends on requirements and your team's skill sets.  Learning ASP.NET (MVC or WebForms) is typically a long, hard road if you come from a WinForms background (and arguably, if you are doing WebForms, you may as well so Silverlight). If you have a lot of experience with HTML/CSS/JavaScript(jQuery)/MVC patterns, then ASP.NET MVC will probably suit your project better.  If you have requirements such as cross-browser compatability, SEO or other weby things, you'll probably go ASP.NET MVC.

On a recent project, where we had an assessment of the requirements and available technology options, we were forced down the ASP.NET MVC by the client but we had determined that given the team and requirements, Silverlight would have been an easier (read: less expensive) technology to implement the application in and it would have reduced the project cost by 50%. (educated, thumb in air guess)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the biggest delays are caused by "black holes" - things that you'd assumed were going to be easy when you put together your estimates, which turn out to be hard/complicated/time-consuming due to leaky abstractions, framework bugs, and so on.

I'd therefore favour an approach which uses proven technology and protocols and minimal abstraction, and for me, that would be ASP.NET MVC. But make sure your developers understand HTTP, HTML, the model-view-controller pattern and the fundamentals of stateless architecture.