# Is WPF development faster or slower than classic ASP.NET (web forms)

Tags: asp.net, wpf, estimation

Are you experienced with both ASP.NET and WPF coding? If so, I'll be grateful if you'll share your experience, please.

We are estimating a 100-screen WPF project. Our estimation methodology involves characterizing the complexity of each screen. We then apply a standard number for the development time, based on the complexity and the technology. The standard number is based on the developer being *good*, not a super-star.

For example, here's a screen:

> The user selects a row in the master
>   grid, then edits the data in the
>   detail and saves the changes. Ajax is
>   used to populate and save the detail
>   without a postback. The data layer is
>   already there, and styling will be
>   handled by someone else. The task includes writing an appropriate suite of unit tests; integration testing is separate.

We would characterize this screen as *medium* and allocate *X hours* for the task, for classic ASP.NET (as opposed to MVC).

We need help figuring out what *X* should be for WPF.

**My question:**

If the screen was being created in WPF, by someone *good* at WPF -- would it take X hours, or .7 X, or 1.3 X? What is the relative productivity of WPF vs classic ASP.NET?

Asking another way: If a task takes (picking a number) 10 hours of ASP.NET coding, how many hours would it take to do it with WPF? 5? 15?

We'd like to know if WPF is (picking a number) 50% more productive than ASP.NET, so we can propose a lower price and be confident that we will be able to do the project within budget.

[Edit] Asking yet another way: This discussion [ASP.Net or WPF (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207525/asp-net-or-wpf-c) has a bunch of responses. The selected "correct" answer is "Reasons to choose WPF" and the first reason is "Much faster and easier development than ASP.NET and jQuery".

Is that answer true? How *much* faster?

Comment: WPF is more of a client-side thing while ASP.NET is a server-side thing. You're comparing two totally different sides of .NET. (For what it's worth, I've learned the ropes of ASP.NET WebForms and am a newcomer to WPF.)

Comment: I don't know if it's fair to compare apples to oranges. In any case I think this is more like programmers.SE material.

Comment: Wait, if you don't have anyone with enough WPF experience to be able to provide an estimate, the answer is probably "No, it won't be faster."

Comment: I don't think it's as apples to oranges as you are implying. The languages, conventions, and frameworks are the same. Ruby on Rails and ASP.NET are both web frameworks, but that's probably more apples to oranges as it requires learning a new language and framework. Moving from ASP.NET to WPF does not require as much of a skillset change.

Comment: BoltClock: ASP.NET is used to create web pages -- on the client. Right?

Comment: Martinho: What is programmers SE material? Google finds that phrase in one other place, also in StackOverflow. I don't get the apples and oranges thing. The database, data layer, business objects are the same. They are different UIs for exposing those things. Can one UI be created faster than the other? Regarding your second comment, about not enough WPF experience: Right, we don't have the experience, but we have to get this estimate done. WPF pros will do the coding, but they're not available to help with the estimate. NOW can you give me your view about WPF's relative productivity, please?

Comment: @Hoyster, I have spent about twelve years coding in the web domain, and approximately 200 hours working in WPF, so take this as you will. In my opinion, the productivity of a person or team in WPF will be very low unless their experience with WPF is very high. Assuming your "good" programmer is walking in to this with zero experience at either web or wpf tech, they'll get the wheels turning in web much, much faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From **personal** experience:

ASP.NET is easier to get into than WPF. ASP.NET quite similar to other web server side technologies. WPF breaks with and adds many features to classic desktop development, that takes time getting used to.

That said, actual development by **experienced** developers might be a lot faster in WPF. My personal stress factor is browser compatibility (getting it to render exactly the same way in multiple (versions of) browsers; it simply takes too much time.)

You are not going to get any numbers from me as it is much to hard to give them based on the input you have given.

Comment: Oh, of course, browser madness! That should have been at the top of my list of ASP.NET pain points. Lacking anything better, thus far -- I'll interpret your "might be a lot faster in WPF" as 33% faster. I double-dog dare you to correct that number. What's up, McFly -- CHICKEN!?? (Forgive my resorting to school yard psychology, but I really need a number.)

Comment: The only 'sane'number I can give you is 42... Seriously: you are fooling yourself (and others) when just picking a number. At least add a margin to it to indicate how certain you are of this number. (Also: the way you are acting here almost feels like trolling)

Comment: Apologies for the troll-like tone. Didn't realize. Was trying for amusing, obviously missed. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @hoyster: no worries. Numbers should be backed up with real data. Just shouting a number will seriously deflate the meaning of the number.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many variables. The number 1 reason to pick a tool is because of user familiarity. If your team already knows and is comfortable with ASP.NET it will be several magnitudes better and faster using that. If your team does not know WPF, then there will be a ramp up period, and once they are fully ramped up, they will probably be just as fast as they were with ASP.NET.

However, if the requirement is that the app can be installed, or is needed offline, or has some other benefit that only comes with WPF, then you probably need to take the hit. If not, you'll have a more quality product if you let the team use the tools they are comfortable with.

If you are trying to keep your concerns separated and doing a Model View Presenter style approach with asp.net, I think that takes longer and is more work than MVVM in WPF, because there is great support for binding. But still, there is a learning curve.

There is nothing implicit to asp.net or WPF that makes one more rapid than the other. What determines the speed of development is the talent of the team and what they are comfortable with.

Comment: "There is nothing implicit to asp.net or WPF that makes one more rapid than the other" Are you speaking from actual experience? It sounds to me like you're just side-stepping the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, NerdFury. I guess I didn't make it clear, that programmer ability is a constant -- a good ASP.NET coder and a good WPF coder. The question is not whether to use WPF or ASP.NET. We are going to use WPF. I'm interested in their relative productivity, which you speak to in your last two paragraphs. Thank-you!

Comment: @Joe white - I have used both ASP.NET and WPF for application development. I'm not sidestepping the question. I'm saying that if I took the my first app approach and used drag and drop controls with logic in the button click events, I would probably be just as fast in either framework. But I can write aspx markup way faster than xaml. I can use MVVM with WPF easier than I can use a MVP pattern in asp.net. It all has to do with comfort, and fun. I code faster when I'm having fun, and using a tool I'm comfortable with. Learning new tools is fun too, but comes at a cost.

Comment: "There is nothing inplicit..." There ARE intrinsic differences, IMO. With ASP.NET, you need to know server controls, HTML and CSS. Throw in Javascript and graphic software if you want a UI that's less than mundane. To avoid postbacks, add Ajax and web services. Straight Javascript, jQuery or some other library? SOAP or REST? JSON, XML, XSLT? You have to handle state and caching, with 5 ways to do each. Your solutions depend on your hardware: web farm, session server? The event model emulates VB6 just well enough to confuse you. WPF: C#, XAML, a solid event model, and Blend for UI goodness.

Comment: @hoyster - The only thing you mentioned that is specific to ASP.NET is server controls. The rest are pretty much optional and are web development vs. client development topics. Not ASP.NET vs WPF. If you have a smart client, you might still have web services and soap/rest issues. If you get data from a db, you still will want to do caching. At the root both have event models, and controls that can be dragged onto a canvas, and then you react to events from controls. What design decisions you take after that affect the complexity outside of either framework.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think WPF is much faster to develop in than ASP.Net, however if you are building an estimate make sure you build in plenty of padding for the learning curve.

I have worked with both and prefer WPF by far. I find it much faster and easier to work with, and creating the UI I want seems so easy compared to anything in Winforms or Web-based.

For example, it is not a problem to do things like create oddly-shaped buttons (starburst, round, etc), create dropdowns w/ checkboxes to filter data, create datagrids which have different UIs for different rows based on the data, popups that make the background semitransparent or blurry, or draggable objects that actually show the object being dragged. These are all things I have played with which are very simple in WPF.

When I first started working with WPF there wasn't a lot of support out there for it, but I believe that has changed. Most problems I encounter have a solution somewhere online, or the answer can be obtained quickly by asking on SO

The one limitation I see with WPF is that it is tied with the .Net framework

Answer (score 0):

I think its safe to say that WPF, in such a project as you describe can be 33% faster, basically because the results are more predictable and controllable.  In the end, everyone wants it to look like they want it to look.

WPF is much more naturally reusable and scalable than any ASP.NET project could be.  Everything you build can be easily turned into a user control with binding built in.  I prefer MVVM to MVC.

I would say you can get something (like a database view) working faster in ASP.NET, but to get it to look like you want will be a lot harder.  So your development time really is dependent on how flexible your UI requirements are.  If you want to make a new control, it will take a lot longer in ASP.NET and be harder to describe how to use that control to others.

I also started programming recently with VB6 for desktop apps and JQuery with PHP.  Development goes a lot faster with these languages than with anything .NET related, because .NET must be compiled.  This is a major major drawback to this language.  Often it can take quite some time to compile a complicated website.  For this reason, for my own personal use, I will stick with jQuery, PHP web services and MySQL.